# How do I Set Timer Control According to User entry in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I need help regarding timer control, I wanted to set time after user entry i.e. after form run's user enter in textbox
10:30 AM then timer on label will start from 10:30 AM to continue..

Comment: Please mention what kind of windows application? Forms? WPF?

Comment: Is this like an alarm or countdown timer!?

Comment: Its Windows Forms Application and yes its like countdown timer.. :)..

**like user enter 10:35 AM then application continue with that time..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code hope its helpful.....

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       static Int32 sec = 0;
       static Int32 minut = 0;
       string m;
       string s;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         m = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2);
        s = textBox1.Text.Substring(3, 2);
        sec = Convert.ToInt32(s);

        minut = Convert.ToInt32(m);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sec++;
        if(sec>59)
        {
            sec = 1;
            minut++;
        }
        if(minut>59)
        {
            minut = 0;
        }

        label1.Text = minut.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString();
        //second = second + 1;
        //if (second >= 10)
        //{
        //    timer1.Stop();
        //    MessageBox.Show("Exiting from Timer....");
        //}
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I trying to implement this logic :)

Comment: Thank you all..Finally I got my solution :)

Comment: welcome hope u come again on stack overflow..........

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using a basic BackGroundWorker to advance a clock for 60 seconds from the date/time entered in a WinForms application. If you'd rather use the actual time, change DateTime begin = DateTime.Parse(textbox_1.Text); to DateTime begin = DateTime.Now; -- it's not the world's most glamorous solution, but it'll get the job done ad be something to think about, anyway. Good luck!

```
System.ComponentModel.BackGroundWorker textTime = new System.ComponentModel.BackGroundWorker();// use a reference Using System.ComponentModel; to avoid all this typing
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){//this event could be a button click, or whatever else you want to start the process
    textTime.DoWork+= beginTextTimer;
    textTime.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void beginTextTimer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
     DateTime begin = DateTime.Parse(textbox_1.Text);//assumes you've already done validation - use DateTime.Now if you don't require user's input
     int totalSeconds = 0;
     While(totalSeconds < 60){
        totalSeconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin).TotalSeconds;//since you're pausing 1 second, you could just increment an integer here rather than doing a DateTime calculation - this works no matter what the pause is
         MethodInvoker mI = () => { 
             textBox_1.Text = begin.AddSeconds(totalSeconds).ToString(); 
         };
         BeginInvoke(mI);//these two lines invoke back to the UI thread to change the textbox value    
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);     
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ..will try and let you know :)

Comment: I tried same code its working fine..but its take system time continuously..
My problem is.. I want to start time according to user entry..Like user enter in text box 10:35 AM then countdown start from 10:35 to continue till user stop or close the application :)..

Comment: You want how many minutes and seconds since the user clicked?

Comment: The code I sent you does parse the user's input (not system time) but it parses a date/time. I think you want time only. Is it all in one textbox 10:35 PM and is the text to be 12 hour or 24 hour?

Comment: Yes :) the time will continue increase till user press end or close the application..